# ASP.NET MVC AuthorizeAttribute Inheritence

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, inheritance

I created a custom authorize attribute filter class called `BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute` by inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` and overriding appropriate methods. That all works great. However, the thing I ran into that I'm not understanding is that I tried to create another  filter that inherits from `BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute` and just override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method so I can handle different actions differently. For some reason when I apply the attribute to an action method the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` that belongs to `BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute` is being called instead of the new method.

Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm applying the attributes to the action methods? Is there something else I need to do? is the `AttributeUsage` on the `AjaxAuthorizationAttribute` class even necessary?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AjaxAuthorizationAttribute : BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute
{
}

[BasicHttpAuthorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
}

public class MyController : BaseController
{
    [BasicHttpAuthorize(/* other properties */)]
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
    }

    [AjaxAuthorization]
    public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: @Colin, can you remove [BasicHttpAuthorize] out of BaseController. I think the problem comes from having 2 authorize attributes for your someOtherAction.